# numero de carteres por linea vs code

Tags: html5, php7, vscode

Cuando formateo el codigo HTML en archivos .php las lineas se cortan caprichosamente, ej. tengo esta linea:

```
<button type="button" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas"><iclass="ti ti-x"></i></button>
```

Despues de shif+alt+f para dar formato e indentar el codigo queda asi:

```
<button type="button" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas"><i
class="ti ti-x"></i></button>
```

Este comportamiento comenzo de la nada, tambien se desaparecieron varias extesiones.

Es posible configurar el numero de caracteres por linea de tal manera que quede a gusto del usuario; pues tengo monitor grande y me gusta ver la lineas completa o cortarlas donde se me antoje

Comment: Si te desaparecieron varias extensiones, es posible que una de ellas fuese el formatter que tenías antes. Descárgala de nuevo, ponlo como formateador por defecto y debería seguirte como antes. Personalmente uso prettier para el formateo, es bastante configurable en muchas cosas... En cuanto a cómo configurarlo, pues es que dependerá de qué formateador estés usando!